# Inconsistency in the $2\to 2$ kinematics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, kinematics, collision, scattering

I must be confusing something horribly, because this should be very simple, but I am keep getting inconsistent results in the basic 2->2 scattering kinematics.

Let the process be $$a(p_1) + b(p_2) \to c (k_1) + d(k_2)$$
Take the $b,c,d$ to be massless particles $p_2^2=k_1^2=k_2^2=0.$ On the other hand, $p_1^2 = -Q^2<0$. Note that $p_1$ is taken to be spacelike in the $(+,-,-,-)$ signature. This is because I'm secretly interested in the deep-inelastic scattering case, where $a$ is the spacelike virtual photon. Anyways, if we now take the CM frame of $a,b$, we can then parameterize the momenta as

$$p_1 = (p_{10},0,0,-p_{2z}) \\
p_2 = (p_{2z},0,0,p_{2z}) \\
k_1 = (k_{0},k_0\sin\theta,0,k_{0}\cos\theta) \\
k_2 = (k_{0},-k_0\sin\theta,0,-k_{0}\cos\theta) \\
$$

Furthermore, we let $x \equiv \frac{Q^2}{2p_1 \cdot p_2}$, this is the Bjorken variable.
Now, if we solve for

$$p_{10}^2 - p_{2z}^2=-Q^2\\
p_1\cdot p_2 = \frac{Q^2}{2x} = p_{10}p_{2z} + p_{2z}^2\\
s=(p_1+p_2)^2=Q^2\frac{1-x}{x}=4k_0^2=(k_1+k_2)^2$$
we get
$$p_{10}^2=\frac{Q^2(1-2x)^2}{4x(1-x)}\,,\\
p_{2z}^2=\frac{Q^2}{4x(1-x)}\,,\\
k_{0}^2=\frac{1}{4}Q^2\frac{1-x}{x}\,.$$

This makes me conclude that $p_{10}$ is actually piecewise function, namely
$$p_{10}= \sqrt{p_{10}^2}=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{Q}{2\sqrt{x(1-x)}}(1-2x)&\text{if}\, x\leq \frac{1}{2}\,,\\
 \frac{Q}{2\sqrt{x(1-x)}}(2x-1)&\text{if}\, x> \frac{1}{2}\,.
\end{cases}
$$
Now, this quickly leads to the contradiction.
For example, the Mandelstam variable $t= (p_2-k_2)^2=(k_1-p_1)^2 $.

From the first relation
$$t=(p_2-k_2)^2 = -2p_2\cdot k_2 = -2p_{2z}k_0 (1+\cos\theta)=-\frac{Q^2}{2x}(1+\cos\theta).$$
On the other hand, the second relation gives
$$t=(k_1-p_1)^2 = -Q^2-2p_1\cdot k_1 = -Q^2-2k_0 (p_{10}+p_{2z}\cos\theta)=-\frac{Q^2}{2x}(2x+\sqrt{(1-2x)^2}+\cos\theta).$$
Now, this is only consistent with the first case if $\sqrt{(1-2x)^2} = (1-2x)$, which holds true when $x\leq \frac{1}{2}$. This seems odd to me, especially since I'm not aware of Bjorken variable $x$ being bounded above by $\frac{1}{2}$. What is the reason for this inconsistency? Why does it appear that I need to take $x\leq \frac{1}{2}$? Thank you.

Edit:

Indeed, I was just being dumb.
$$p_{10}^2 - p_{2z}^2=-Q^2\\
p_1\cdot p_2 = \frac{Q^2}{2x} = p_{10}p_{2z} + p_{2z}^2$$
uniquely gives
$$p_{10}=\frac{Q(1-2x)}{2\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,.$$
Therefore, there is no two piecewise solutions to $p_{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the discrepancy between the two methods comes from the fact that in the first method, you did not really isolate $p_{10}$. It is still there hidden in the variable x.
$$
x = \frac{Q^2}{2p_{10}p_{2z} + p_{2z}^2} \\
$$

Comment: I do not follow what you mean. I solved for p10, p2z, k0 with respect to x first. Why would using that expression cause any issue